# What kind of switch do I need to emergency stop a dc motor?

Tags: switches, relay, dc-motor

I have a DC motor - 48v - 1000w - ~20A and I'm controlling its speed using a PWM.

When I plug my 48v battery, the only protection I currently have is my main Mosfet that acts like a switch. If the gate is not opened, no current is flowing.

If the Mosfet burns for any reason, it currently means the motor will run at full speed which is **very dangerous**.

So I was thinking about putting a switch between my 48v battery and my DC motor. Thereby, I'll be able to turn on/off manually if something bad happens. Another solution could be putting a relay and control it through a small signal with my arduino board.

I can't find on the internet what's the best solution. Especially because I can't find a switch or a relay that can support ~30A - 48v with a decent price.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: How do you need the motor to stop?

Comment: *Safety has no price*. It sounds very common place but it is true. How much value is your motor or what is connected to it, or your fingers? The reason why emergency stop buttons are so expensive is because they have a very, very low failure rate. Look for 'battery emergency switch'.

Comment: Thanks! Does something like this could be the solution? https://www.banggood.com/300A-Battery-Power-ON-OFF-Disconnect-Rotary-Isolator-Kill-Switch-Boat-Car-Van-Truck-p-1008959.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN

Comment: It is  switch and can handle the current. It just takes a bit longer to operate then an emergency switch. You have to make the final decision, I can't do that.

Comment: Safety should be redundant and of different types. Add a mains disconnect feature. I have seen massive lever assemblies that would pull the plug

Comment: @SandroMunda: That switch is a poor choice as it has to be gripped and twisted. In an emergency you might miss. You are looking for a high-current mushroom head emergency stop switch. Contacts should be forced (not sprung) apart when the button is pressed.

Comment: I totally agree that a mushroom button or a tether kill switch would be the best solution but I can't find any of them available on internet that supports at least 48v - 30amps :/

Comment: If you are asking these questions, with no experience, yet a full speed motor will be very dangerous, you should rethink whether this project is the appropriate use of your software talents.